# Ignore an empty nodeValue in a XML file

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm haveing a problem skipping empty nodeValues. Below I'm creating a object by reading different tags from a XML file. The problem is that when try to read nodeValue for "Addresse5" I'm getting an error saying the nodevalue is undefined.

```
    var getCustomerAddress1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('address1');
    var getCustomerAddress2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('address2');
    var getCustomerAddress3 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('address3');
    var getCustomerAddress4 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('address4');
    var getCustomerAddress5 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('address5');
    var getCustomerNumber = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('customerNumber');


var txt2 = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

        txt2 = {

            Addresse1: getCustomerAddress1[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
            Addresse2: getCustomerAddress2[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
            Addresse3: getCustomerAddress3[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
            Addresse4: getCustomerAddress4[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
            Addresse5: getCustomerAddress5[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,

        };
    }
```

What I want is to skip the reading or replacing the empty nodeValue with some text but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

EDIT:

This is how my xml file looks like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<collection>
    <DeliveryAddress>
        <address1>sdasdsadsa</address1>
        <address2>1asdasdas1</address2>
        <address3>sdfsdf</address3>
        <address4>Daasdasd</address4>
        <address5></address5>
        <customerNumber>5825252</customerNumber>
    </DeliveryAddress>
</collection>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function that filters undefined values and replaces them with empty strings or whatever you like and pass the value to it, whenever you cannot be sure if an allowed value is present in the XML document.

```
var getCustomerAddress1 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('address1');
var getCustomerAddress2 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('address2');
var getCustomerAddress3 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('address3');
var getCustomerAddress4 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('address4');
var getCustomerAddress5 = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('address5');
var getCustomerNumber = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('customerNumber');

// function to add
function filterUndefined(xmlValue) {
    if (xmlValue != null) { // check if type is null or undefined
        return xmlValue;
    }
    else {
        return ""; // return empty string or anything else you like
    }
}

var txt2 = {};
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    // when filling this object with values, filter undefined ones and replace them with ""
    txt2 = {

        Addresse1: filterUndefined(getCustomerAddress1[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue),
        Addresse2: filterUndefined(getCustomerAddress2[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue),
        Addresse3: filterUndefined(getCustomerAddress3[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue),
        Addresse4: filterUndefined(getCustomerAddress4[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue),
        Addresse5: filterUndefined(getCustomerAddress5[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue),

    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to the solution you mentioned but it seems like the value isn't being changed when the value is undefined. I still get the same error..

Comment: @DilanRashied I changed the validation to also filter null values. Maybe the nodeValues are not really undefined but null. That is a little bit confusing in js.

Comment: Thanks it seems like it just ignores the filterUndefined function even if I set it to check for undefined or null.

Comment: I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjnopw5p/) and there it is working as expected. The txt2 object gets logged to the console. There you can see for yourself.

Comment: Your code is working, I think the problem is when I'm creating the objects for "txt2". I can run your code as you wrote it, but as soon as i try to get nodeValue i get error if they are undefined using the code you provided

Comment: Could you create a fiddle with the code you have now, so I can have a closer look? Because my code is essentially the same, except I am not processing a real XML file. Maybe there is some other problem.

Comment: Why do you use the customer number to define how often you execute the for loop? Is that the overall number of customers you have? That could be the problem: Suppose you have a customer number '5825252'. By reading it from the XML file, you get that as a string. You take the length of the string which would be 7. So you are looping 7 times through the for loop. But basically you are refilling the same object again and again. Making the last loop the relevant one: It searches for all tags named "address..." with an index of 6. This index does not exist, because every tag is only used one time.

Comment: The getCustomerNumber is an array, so what I'm doing is to take the length of this array and use it for my for loop as i know that for every customer number there is an address

Comment: Oh, I see. I overlooked that part. Now it makes more sense to me. But still you would be refilling the txt2 object over and over again. Is that intentional?

Comment: You're right I did not see that, that is not my intention. What I want to is to save all values with the tags address1, address2 and so on to "txt2"

Comment: Do you want to have multiple addresses for every customer or just one? For me it looks like you want to have multiple addresses.

Comment: Yes exactly I want to have muliple addresses

Comment: Could you already achieve this goal or do you still need help? I'm just asking because you marked the answer as correct.

Comment: The problem is solved, I appreciate your time! Your solution was spot on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [continue operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) using [for in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) like this:

```
for(var prop in txt2){
  if(prop.length < 1) continue //skips if length is less than 1
  //perform your task now...
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your solution by adding               
  txt2 = {

Addresse1: getCustomerAddress1[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
Addresse2: getCustomerAddress2[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
Addresse3: getCustomerAddress3[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
Addresse4: getCustomerAddress4[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
Addresse5: getCustomerAddress5[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue,

                };

inside the if statement in ur code example. "txt2" returns an empty object now.